# SELECT ID of Polygon in which a lat-lon lies in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, intersection

I am trying to get the ID of the polygon in which a particular coordinate lies. I have two tables, one which the lat-lon is stored and other table polygons in which the polygons are stored as (lon1 lat1, lon2 lat2 .....). I use this very frequently in MS-SQL but am facing some issues converting the same query to BigQuery

My efforts till now:

```
MS-SQL


SELECT  DISTINCT ID, P.ID AS POLYGON_ID
FROM LOCATIONS as L
LEFT OUTER JOIN POLYGONS as P ON 
ON P.POLYGON.STIntersects(geography::Point(L.[LAT], L.[LON], 4326)) = 1
```

```
BigQuery

SELECT DISTINCT ID,p.id as POLYGON_ID
from locations L
LEFT OUTER JOIN polygons p
ON p.polygon.ST_INTERSECTION(ST_GEOGPOINT(l.lon, l.lat)) =1
```

Any examples or materials that can direct me are welcome. Thanks

Comment: You are asking for an external reference, so I'm voting to close.  However, I will point you to the BQ GIS documentation:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data.

Comment: Yes, I am going through this documentation. I am not specifically fixated about external reference. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT l.id, p.id AS polygon_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) geo
  FROM `project.dataset.locations`
) l
JOIN (
  SELECT id, ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POLYGON((' || polygon || '))') geo
  FROM `project.dataset.polygons`
) p  
ON ST_WITHIN(l.geo, p.geo)
```

You can test, play with above using sample/dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.polygons` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1' AS polygon UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '3 3, 3 4, 4 4, 4 3, 3 3'
), `project.dataset.locations` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1.5 lon, 1.5 lat UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 3.5, 3.5 
)
SELECT l.id, p.id AS polygon_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) geo
  FROM `project.dataset.locations`
) l
JOIN (
  SELECT id, ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POLYGON((' || polygon || '))') geo
  FROM `project.dataset.polygons`
) p  
ON ST_WITHIN(l.geo, p.geo)
```

with output

```
Row id  polygon_id   
1   1   1    
2   2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT L.ID, P.ID AS POLYGON_ID
FROM LOCATIONS as L
JOIN POLYGONS as P ON 
ST_INTERSECTS(ST_GEOGPOINT(L.lon,L.lat),P.polygon)
```

where `P.polygon` is stored in the format `(lon_1 lat_1, lon_2 lat_2 .....lon_n, lat_n)`.